# Can not build any shared libraries in ATLAS

Tags: installation, shared-libraries, lapack, atlas

```
cp /home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libsatlas.dylib /usr/local/atlas/lib/.
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libsatlas.dylib’: No such file or directory
make[1]: [install_lib] Error 1 (ignored)
cp /home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libtatlas.dylib /usr/local/atlas/lib/.
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libtatlas.dylib’: No such file or directory
make[1]: [install_lib] Error 1 (ignored)
cp /home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libsatlas.dll /usr/local/atlas/lib/.
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libsatlas.dll’: No such file or directory
make[1]: [install_lib] Error 1 (ignored)
cp /home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libtatlas.dll /usr/local/atlas/lib/.
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libtatlas.dll’: No such file or directory
make[1]: [install_lib] Error 1 (ignored)
cp /home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libsatlas.so /usr/local/atlas/lib/.
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libsatlas.so’: No such file or directory
make[1]: [install_lib] Error 1 (ignored)
cp /home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libtatlas.so /usr/local/atlas/lib/.
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib/libtatlas.so’: No such file or directory
make[1]: [install_lib] Error 1 (ignored)
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build'
```

The instruction I use is:

```
mkdir build
cd build 
../configure
make
make install
```

Then is gives the error above.

I also try to run `make shared` in the `lib` directory.
But it says:

```
make TRYALL outso=libsatlas.so \
                libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a" \
                LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
if make GCCTRY outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt gcc and all libs" ; \
        elif make LDTRY outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt ld and all sys libs" ; \
elif make GCCTRY_norp outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt gcc and all libs and no rpath" ; \
        elif make GCCTRY outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt gcc and all C libs" ; \
        elif make LDTRY outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt ld and -lc -lgcc" ; \
        elif make GCCTRY_norp outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt gcc and all C libs and no rpath" ; \
        elif make GCCTRY outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt gcc and all libs except -lgcc" ; \
        elif make LDTRY outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt all libs except -lgcc" ; \
        elif make GCCTRY_norp outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt gcc and all libs except -lgcc, no rpath" ; \
        elif make GCCTRY outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-lc -lpthread -lm" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt gcc and -lc" ; \
        elif make LDTRY outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-lc -lpthread -lm" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt ld and -lc" ; \
        elif make GCCTRY_norp outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-lc -lpthread -lm" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt gcc and -lc, no rpath" ; \
        elif make LDTRY outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-lpthread -lm" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt ld" ; \
        elif make GCCTRY_norp outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
        LIBS="-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lkernel32" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib"; then \
           echo "libsatlas.so built wt fortran and kernel32, no rpath" ; \
        else \
           make GCCTRY outso="libsatlas.so" libas="liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a"  \
           LIBS="-lpthread -lm" LIBINSTdir="/usr/local/atlas/lib" ; \
        fi
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
/usr/bin/gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -m64 -shared -o libsatlas.so  \
           -Wl,"-rpath-link /usr/local/atlas/lib" \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: bad -rpath option
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GCCTRY] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
ld -melf_x86_64 -shared -soname /usr/local/atlas/lib/libsatlas.so -o libsatlas.so \
           -rpath-link /usr/local/atlas/lib  \
           --whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a --no-whole-archive -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc
ld: liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
make[2]: *** [LDTRY] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
/usr/bin/gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -m64 -shared -o libsatlas.so  \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GCCTRY_norp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
/usr/bin/gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -m64 -shared -o libsatlas.so  \
           -Wl,"-rpath-link /usr/local/atlas/lib" \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: bad -rpath option
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GCCTRY] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
ld -melf_x86_64 -shared -soname /usr/local/atlas/lib/libsatlas.so -o libsatlas.so \
           -rpath-link /usr/local/atlas/lib  \
           --whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a --no-whole-archive -lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc
ld: liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
make[2]: *** [LDTRY] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
/usr/bin/gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -m64 -shared -o libsatlas.so  \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lc -lpthread -lm -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GCCTRY_norp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
/usr/bin/gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -m64 -shared -o libsatlas.so  \
           -Wl,"-rpath-link /usr/local/atlas/lib" \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm
/usr/bin/ld: bad -rpath option
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GCCTRY] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
ld -melf_x86_64 -shared -soname /usr/local/atlas/lib/libsatlas.so -o libsatlas.so \
           -rpath-link /usr/local/atlas/lib  \
           --whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a --no-whole-archive -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm
ld: liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
make[2]: *** [LDTRY] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
/usr/bin/gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -m64 -shared -o libsatlas.so  \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lc -lpthread -lm
/usr/bin/ld: liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GCCTRY_norp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
/usr/bin/gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -m64 -shared -o libsatlas.so  \
           -Wl,"-rpath-link /usr/local/atlas/lib" \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lc -lpthread -lm
/usr/bin/ld: bad -rpath option
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GCCTRY] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
ld -melf_x86_64 -shared -soname /usr/local/atlas/lib/libsatlas.so -o libsatlas.so \
           -rpath-link /usr/local/atlas/lib  \
           --whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a --no-whole-archive -lc -lpthread -lm
ld: liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
make[2]: *** [LDTRY] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
/usr/bin/gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -m64 -shared -o libsatlas.so  \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lc -lpthread -lm
/usr/bin/ld: liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GCCTRY_norp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
ld -melf_x86_64 -shared -soname /usr/local/atlas/lib/libsatlas.so -o libsatlas.so \
           -rpath-link /usr/local/atlas/lib  \
           --whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a --no-whole-archive -lpthread -lm
ld: liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
make[2]: *** [LDTRY] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
/usr/bin/gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -m64 -shared -o libsatlas.so  \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -lgfortran  -lkernel32
/usr/bin/ld: liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
liblapack.a(ATL_dgelqf.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GCCTRY_norp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
/usr/bin/gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -m64 -shared -o libsatlas.so  \
           -Wl,"-rpath-link /usr/local/atlas/lib" \
           -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack.a libf77blas.a libcblas.a libatlas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lpthread -lm
/usr/bin/ld: bad -rpath option
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GCCTRY] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make[1]: *** [TRYALL] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gt/ATLAS/build/lib'
make: *** [fat_shared] Error 2
```

Comment: ../configure --shared

Comment: Doesn't work! :/